# spring with kotlin scheduled annotation getting params from properties file

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I am using spring 5 with kotlin and I have the following code

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${job.notification.expiring.x}")
fun notify() {

}
```

and in application.yml

```
job:
  notification:
    expiring.x: 0 0 12 1/1 * ?
```

On the line with the `@schedulled`, at `cron` parameter annotation Intellij says

`An annotation parameter must be a compile-time constant.`

How can I fix this, in Java the properties were loaded at run time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to escape the $ character in Kotlin since this is used for String templates:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "\${job.notification.expiring.x}")
```

See the section on String templates at the bottom of this page:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html

Comment: Any chance you know how you would do that with the fixedDelay attribute. when i do `@Scheduled(fixedDelay = "\${node.checkInInterval}")` it says it requires a Long not a String

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek Yes you need to use fixedDelayString instead of fixedDelay :)

Comment: Yeah, I discovered that 5 minute after i posted ;) , thinks anyway, It´s nice to find others that come back when the SO inbox lights up!